# JSoup parsing badly structured HTML

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have HTML structure that looks like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some other text</p>

<h1>Some other title</h1>
<h2>Another sub-title</h2>
<p>Some other text</p>
```

Basically they're articles but each article is not inside a single div. So what draws them apart is the  tag. I am interested in parsing the paragraph texts only, where each article should be a separate entity.

What I was thinking about: get the container where the articles are stored in, find the first h1 tag. Start parsing all elements until we reach another h1 tag. When a new h1 tag is reached, process the previously parsed data and start anew.

But I was wondering if a simpler solution is possible?

Comment: FWIW, that's already quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only refine your solution a tiny bit:

1. Select all `h1` elements within the container (rather than just searching through the container's elements one by one)
2. For each matching `h1`

   1. Gather up its following siblings until the first `h1`
   2. Process them

[`select`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) lets you find the `h1`s (e.g., `.select("selector-for-container > h1")`, then [`nextElementSibling`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#nextElementSibling--) lets you easily traverse forward from each `h1` (or [`nextSibling`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#nextSibling--), but then you have to weed out the non-elements yourself — of course, if there's article content that *isn't* in a `p`, you'd want this for the text nodes).

Comment: I was thinking of something like a getElementsBetween method, where I'd specify as arguments two element objects (each pair of h1 tags) - Is there such premade method in JSoup?

Comment: @i712345: I don't see one in the API docs. (I was kind of hoping there'd be one, like jQuery's `nextUntil`.)

Comment: I guess It's pretty good time for a pull request then :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @i712345: **Excellent** idea.